# Page number alignment

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{ \textbf{ \small \textsf{\thepage}}}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\begin{document}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

With this code, I have the number of pages: one on the left and one the right. I ask how can change it all on the middle? And the first page of each chapter (which contains the `minitoc`) is without number, I ask how can add a number of page in this page?

Comment: Please expand your code to a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. don't use `\include`. There are packages that produce filler text, e.g. `lipsum`, `blindtext`, or `kantlipsum`. Make sure to include things like minitocs, but don't just paste your original document, reduce it to the minimum necessary to show all features present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part of your question should be fixed with this...

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\small\textsf{\thepage}}}
```

To change the plain fancy page style, which gets called at the start of the chapter

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
     \fancyfoot{}
     \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\small\textsf{\thepage‌​}}}
}
```

The above can also be used to create a new fancy page style by changing plain to xyz, for example, I have used this for various documents, it is a more comprehensive command than the above, since it resets everything first via the \fancyhf{} command.

```
%Header and Footer.
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancypagestyle{detailed}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
    \fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{Page. \thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
 }
```

Then you can call

```
\thispagestyle{detailed}
```

for a single (local) instance, or,

```
\pagestyle{detailed}
```

to set the pagestyle from that point forward or until something else changes it.

Comment: For the minitoc this is the package \usepackage[french]{minitoc}, i'll edit my question

Comment: are you also using fancychap?

Comment: no, just pagestyle{fancy}

Comment: i have in the beginning of chapter \thispagestyle{empty} , when i delete it i have the number of page but it haven't the same style like other pages

Comment: when i add \fancypagestyle{plain} i have lost the style of number i have defined..

Comment: @researcher: You need to include it to the full extent listed in ADP's answer. Not just `\fancypagestyle{plain}`, but `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` where `...` contains your new `plain` page style definition.

Comment: @Werner i have done like that \pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{ \textbf{ \small \textsf{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\scshape  \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\scshape  \leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
} but i have errors!

Comment: @researcher, can you put your query in a new question. I think that your issue has to do with the renewcommand w/ arguments. Cheers.

Comment: @ADP http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88833/page-number-on-the-first-page-of-chapter