# Page number on the first page of Chapter

Tags: page-numbering

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{ \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}     
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{}   
\fancyfoot[C]{ \textbf{ \small \textsf{\thepage}}} \fancyhead[LE]{\scshape \rightmark}      
\fancyhead[RO]{\scshape \leftmark} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}     
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} } 
\begin{document}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

i have used this code to add page number to the first page of each chapter (which contains the minitoc), I have errors, Have you an idea please ?

Comment: You shouldn't redefine `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` as part of `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`. Moreover, you need to add also the settings for the "normal" page style.

Comment: You have to add `\usepackage{titlesec}` and `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` in your preamble too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you were trying to achieve with the `\renewcommands` in the defined fancypagestyle, or how exactly they were going to recieve an argument...

Also you need the `fancyhdr` package. I have added `lastpage` package because I felt like it, and god spoke to me in a dream last night, suggesting that this might happen. God was like the old spice guy, and a little like Morgan Freeman, but with more freckles. Try the following, let me know if it is on the right track.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{MYFANCY}{
    \fancyhf{}
    %\renewcommand{\chaptermark}{\markboth{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{}}     
    %\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}    

    \fancyhead[RO]{\scshape \rightmark}      
    \fancyhead[LE]{\scshape \leftmark}  
    \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize{Pg. \thepage~/~\pageref{LastPage}}}

    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}     
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} 
} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{MYFANCY}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Another Section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: i have already the two packages fancyhdr and lastpage before i ask the question , i try your solution it did'nt work for me

Comment: well the MWE you provided was missing the package references, didn't compile, and you haven't stated exactly what you want. The code you provided was a MNWE, a minimum Non-working example.